# How to create a selected-state color for a CoreGraphics-drawn UIButton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton, core-graphics

I've created an diamond shape through CoreGraphics to be used as a UIButton. I'm having issues setting it's pressed state, setting the background color when selected tints the entire frame, and since the diamond-shape-button is drawn, there is no image to use for it's selected state. How can i get it so that the when the diamond-shaped-button is pressed on, only the diamond in the UIButton's view changes color?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an image for the diamond why not make a selected state image and use [UIButton setImage: forState:]?

If you are doing all of the drawing yourself you will need to clip the drawing to the diamond.  ctx is the CGContext you are drawing to.

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef maskCtx = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height, 8, 4 * width, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

UIBezierPath* path = CreateADiamondBezierPath();

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(maskCtx, 0, 0, 0, 1);
CGContextBeginPath(maskCtx);
CGContextAddPath(maskCtx, path.CGPath);
CGContextFillPath(maskCtx);

CGImageRef maskImg = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(maskCtx);

//Clip to the mask
CGContextClipToMask(ctx, scaledFrame, maskImg);

//Now fil in your ctx with the selected color
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 1, 0, 0, 1); //this does red

CFRelease(maskImg);
CFRelease(maskCtx);
```